# Combine 2 query results in separate columns of one query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a database in `Access`, I have 2 tables with relationship like so :

```
  Nodes . . . . .  Relation . . . . . Links

 -------- . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .----------------

| ID . .|----------------------------| Near End |

| Lat . | . . . . . . . . . | . . . . . . | . . . . . . . . |


| Lon  | . . . . . . . . . . -----------| far End . .|

 --------- . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ---------------
```

As can be seen, 2 fields on table Links has relation with same field of table Nodes. Now I want, for example, to extract Lat for two ends as below.

Results:

```
[Near End Lat] . . . [Far End Lat]
```

I want more accurate single query. Speed of running is important because tables have too many records and also I will use some complicated conditions.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text. And show us your current query attempt. Before you start, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Can you show the relations of your tables via a screenshot off the relations tab in access and some example data? Your description is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to join to two copies of the Nodes table

[image]

EDIT: pretty sure this is the same thing with a different flavour, but it gives the answer you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually I want to find link information, for example two sides positions,which its Near End is specific Node. Then I'll use its results in my function to draw a line in google earth.

Comment: Then I think you need to provide some example data, and expected results as the other comments have suggested

Comment: I post a new message as an example

Comment: as mentioned in the edit, pretty sure that it's the same thing I posed before, but with a different flavour.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following picture
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qZA9.jpg)
For example, when I search T4322X result may be as bellow:

T4322X, T4322X latitude, T4322X longitude, T4326X, T4326X latitude, T4322X longitude

Answer (score 0):

My Friends,

After some try I found following SQL works properly:

```
SELECT
 Nodes.NodeName, Nodes.Latitude, Nodes.Longitude,
 NN.NodeName, NN.Latitude, NN.Longitude
FROM 
 (Nodes INNER JOIN Links on Nodes.ID=Links.[Near End]) 
 INNER JOIN
 (
      SELECT 
           Nodes.NodeName, Nodes.Latitude, Nodes.Longitude, Links.ID
      FROM
           Nodes INNER JOIN Links on Nodes.ID=Links.[Far End]
 ) AS NN ON NN.ID=Links.ID
WHERE 
 Links.Selected=True;
```